# can't get jqueryui accordion to keep active index on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, postback, accordion

I have looked around and found numerous solutions to this, but for some reason it just isn't working for me.

.NET 4, c#

I have an accordion with three sections. In my c# code behind load section i have...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    MembershipUser websiteUser = Membership.GetUser();
    ProfileCommon websiteUserProfile = Profile.GetProfile(websiteUser.UserName);

    if (websiteUserProfile.PrimaryCompany == "BEL")
        hiddenAccordionIndex.Value = "1";
}
```

this sets the initial active section. This works just fine.

What I want to happen now, is if the active section is switched to say 0, and then a postback occurs on the page, i want the accordion to maintain the active section as 0.

What is actually happening, is the accordion is switching back to 1.

my jquery...

```
    var currentIndex = $("#<%= hiddenAccordionIndex.ClientID %>").val();
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: parseInt(currentIndex),
        change: function (event, ui) {
            var newIndex = $(this).children("h3").index(ui.newHeader);
            $("#<%= hiddenAccordionIndex.ClientID %>").val(newIndex);
        }
    });
```

even if I remove the c# code that set's the initial active section, the behaviour is the same. So I'm sure that this is not the cause of the problem.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong here? I'm stumped!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have the answer.

**change** is not an event. instead i used **activate** and this is now working.

All the solutions i have seen state a **change** event, perhaps this was for an older version!

new code...

```
var currentIndex = $("#<%= hiddenAccordionIndex.ClientID %>").val();
$("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: parseInt(currentIndex),
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var newIndex = $(this).children("h3").index(ui.newHeader);
        $("#<%= hiddenAccordionIndex.ClientID %>").val(newIndex);
    }
});
```